# Sort state object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a way to click on my table header ("First Name", "Last Name" etc) and have the data sort accordingly.

```
        <Container>
        <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th scope="col" >Image</th>
            <th scope="col" value="firstName" onClick={this.sortFirstName}>First Name</th>
            <th scope="col" value="lastName">Last Lame</th>
            <th scope="col" value="email">Email</th>
            <th scope="col" value="phoneNumber">Phone Number</th>
            <th scope="col" value="city">City</th>
            <th scope="col" value="SSN">SSN</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {this.state.filteredEmployeeData.map(ee => (
          <EmployeeData
            id={ee.login.uuid}
            key={ee.login.uuid}
            img={ee.picture.thumbnail}
            firstName={ee.name.first}
            lastName={ee.name.last}
            email={ee.email}
            phone={ee.cell}
            city={ee.location.city}
            ssn={ee.id.value}
          />
        ))}
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </Container>
```

You can see on the First Name that I'm trying to create an onClick function that would allow me to sort the data according to the first name.

Here's an example of how I'm trying to create the function:

```
  sortEmail(){
    console.log('SORTING!!!!')
    const {filteredEmployeeData} = this.state
    const sorted = filteredEmployeeData.sort((a, b) => {
          if (a.email < b.email){
            return -1
        } else if (a.email > b.email){
            return 1
        } else {
          return 0
        }
    })
    console.log('Sorted List: ', sorted)
    this.setState({filteredEmployeeData: sorted})
}
```

Any help here is appreciated!

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. There isn't enough context here to really help effectively. What does your state look like?

Comment: There are a lot of very good tablesorting libraries available for react. Have you considered using one of those? Also, you're probably getting downvotes because your question looks like "please implement tablesorting for me"

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume your data is an array of objects with the properties being passed in as props in the component, you should use the [sort prototype function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Because you are sorting alphabetically and this is an array of objects, you should create a function that sorts alphabetically by the property of the object. It should look something like this:

```js
    function alphabeticalSort (a, b, property) {
        const x = a[property].toLowerCase();
        const y = b[property].toLowerCase();

        return x.localeCompare(y);
    }
```

I like using [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for these cases since it takes into consideration accents and any other special characters.

Here is a demo of roughly what you want:

```js
const exampleData = [
  {firstName: 'Mat', lastName: 'Smith' },
  {firstName: 'Carol', lastName: 'Jameson' },
  {firstName: 'Albert', lastName: 'Simpson' },
  {firstName: 'Hubert', lastName: 'Hughes' },
]

function alphabeticalSort (a, b, property) {
    const x = a[property].toLowerCase();
    const y = b[property].toLowerCase();

    return x.localeCompare(y);
}


const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(exampleData)
  
  const sort = (property) => {
    const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => alphabeticalSort(a, b, property))
    console.warn(sorted)
    setData([...sorted])
  }

  return (
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th onClick={() => sort('firstName')}>First Name</th>
        <th onClick={() => sort('lastName')}>Last Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {data.map((d) => (
        <tr>
          <td>{d.firstName}</td>
          <td>{d.lastName}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: `.sort` mutates the argument, and it's not correct to mutate state. `[..data].sort` or `data.slice().sort()` would be better.